# UISearchbar clearButton forces the keyboard to appear

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uisearchbar, appearance, uisearchbardelegate

I have a UISearchBar which acts as a live filter for a table view.  When the keyboard is dismissed via endEditing:, the query text and the gray circular "clear" button remain. From here, if I tap the gray "clear" button the keyboard reappears as the text is cleared.

How do I prevent this?  If the keyboard is not currently open I want that button to clear the text without reopening the keyboard.

There is a protocol method that gets called when I tap the clear button. But sending the UISearchBar a resignFirstResponder message doesn't have any effect on the keyboard.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is an old question and I just came across the same issue and managed to solve it the following way:

When the `searchBar:textDidChange:` method of the UISearchBarDelegate gets called because of the user tapping the 'clear' button, the searchBar hasn't become the first responder yet, so we can take advantage of that in order to detect when the user in fact intended to clear the search and not bring focus to the searchBar and/or do something else.

To keep track of that, we need to declare a `BOOL` ivar in our viewController that is also the searchBar delegate (let's call it `shouldBeginEditing`) and set it with an initial value of `YES` (supposing our viewController class is called SearchViewController):

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> {
    // all of our ivar declarations go here...
    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;
    ....
}

...
@end



@implementation SearchViewController
...
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        ...
        shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    }
}
...
@end
```

Later on, in the UISearchBarDelegate, we implement the `searchBar:textDidChange:` and `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:` methods:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)bar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"searchBar:textDidChange: isFirstResponder: %i", [self.searchBar isFirstResponder]);
    if(![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // user tapped the 'clear' button
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        // do whatever I want to happen when the user clears the search...
    }
}


- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar {
    // reset the shouldBeginEditing BOOL ivar to YES, but first take its value and use it to return it from the method call
    BOOL boolToReturn = shouldBeginEditing;
    shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}
```

Basically, that's it.

Best

Comment: This does not seem to account for the case that the user is already typing a text (making the searchbar the first responder), and while doing that press the clear button. Do you have a solution for that as well?

Comment: @thgc in that case the keyboard is already 'up'. This solution is for the explicit case when the user taps the 'clear' button and we don't want the keyboard to show up.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Thank you.  I was just about to go through the pain of constructing my own search bar.  UISearchBar has way too many pitfalls and difficulties when trying to implement custom UI and behavior.

Answer (score 33):

I've found that resignFirstResponder doesn't work when textDidChange is called from a touch to the "clear button".  However, using `performSelection: withObject: afterDelay:` seems to be an effective workaround:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(hideKeyboardWithSearchBar:) withObject:searchBar afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void)hideKeyboardWithSearchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];   
}
```

Comment: Spent hours trying to solve a similar problem. This solution works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

I found a pretty safe way to know if the clear button has been pressed, and ignore the times when the user just delete the last character of the UISearchBar. Here it is :

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    _isRemovingTextWithBackspace = ([searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text].length == 0);

    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0 && !_isRemovingTextWithBackspace)
    {
        NSLog(@"Has clicked on clear !");
    }
}
```

Pretty simple and straightforward, isn't it :) ? The only thing to note is that if the user clicks the clear button when editing the UISearchBar's UITextField, you will have two pings, whereas you'll get only one if the user clicks it when it is not being edited.

---

Edit :
I can't test it, but here's the swift version, as per Rotem :

```
var isRemovingTextWithBackspace = false

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
    self.isRemovingTextWithBackspace = (NSString(string: searchBar.text!).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text).characters.count == 0)
    return true
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    if searchText.characters.count == 0 && !isRemovingTextWithBackspace
    { 
        NSLog("Has clicked on clear !")
    }
}
```

@Rotem's update (Swift2):

```
var isRemovingTextWithBackspace = false

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    self.isRemovingTextWithBackspace = (NSString(string: searchBar.text!).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text).characters.count == 0)
    return true
}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.characters.count == 0 && !isRemovingTextWithBackspace {
        NSLog("Has clicked on clear!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Code for swift 2: `var isRemovingTextWithBackspace = false
    
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        self.isRemovingTextWithBackspace = (NSString(string: searchBar.text!).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: text).characters.count == 0)
        return true
    }
    
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.characters.count == 0 && !isRemovingTextWithBackspace {
            NSLog("Has clicked on clear !")
        }
    }
`

Answer (score 8):

I used a combination of @boliva's answer and also @radiospiel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084809/87696) to a different SO question:

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate> {
    // all of our ivar declarations go here...
    BOOL shouldBeginEditing;
    ....
}

...
@end

@implementation SearchViewController
...
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        ...
        shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    }
}
...

- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    // TODO - dynamically update the search results here, if we choose to do that.

    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // The user clicked the [X] button while the keyboard was hidden
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
    }
    else if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        // The user clicked the [X] button or otherwise cleared the text.
        [theSearchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                        withObject: nil
                        afterDelay: 0.1];
    }
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)bar {
    // reset the shouldBeginEditing BOOL ivar to YES, but first take its value and use it to return it from the method call
    BOOL boolToReturn = shouldBeginEditing;
    shouldBeginEditing = YES;
    return boolToReturn;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution from my experience is just to put a `UIButton` (with clear background and no text) above the system clear button and than connect an `IBAction`

With autolayout its just more than easy

```
- (IBAction)searchCancelButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    self.searchBar.text = @"";

    // some of my stuff
    self.model.fastSearchText = nil;
    [self.model fetchData];
    [self reloadTableViewAnimated:NO];

}
```

Comment: this hack an potentially present problems such as if the device is bigger and etc. it's not a sustainable solution

Answer (score 3):

Pressing the "clear" button in a UISearchBar automatically opens the keyboard even if you call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` within the `textDidChange` UISearchBarDelegate method.

To actually hide the keyboard when you press the "x" to clear the UISearchBar, use the following code. This way, even if `textDidChange` gets called while typing something in the UISearchBar, you only hide the keyboard if you delete all the text within it, weather you use the delete button or you click the "x":

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text!.count == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        } else {
            // Code to make a request here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A Swift version of @boliva 's answer.

```swift
class MySearchContentController: UISearchBarDelegate {

    private var searchBarShouldBeginEditing = true

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBarShouldBeginEditing = searchBar.isFirstResponder
    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        defer {
            searchBarShouldBeginEditing = true
        }
        return searchBarShouldBeginEditing
    }
}
```

Comment: This is by far the most elegant working solution! Don't forget searchBar.delegate = self :)

Answer (score 0):

In your endEditing method, why don't you clear the UISearchBar and there? Since that must be where you resign first responder also, it makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. If I resign the searchbar like this:

    - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
 [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }

that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Of of the search bar delegate calls asks you to accept a change from an old value to a new one - you could detect that the new value was nil, along with the old value being not-nil, and an indicator that the user had not typed anything since the keyboard was last up - then in that case resign first responder for the search bar.  Not sure if the keyboard will momentarily display though.

I have a very similar situation and may try that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Touching the clear button results in `searchText` being empty. Another way to achieve this is to check for empty text in `- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)bar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText length] == 0)
    {
        [self dismissSearch];
    }
    else
    {
        self.searchResultsTable.hidden = YES;
        [self handleSearchForString:searchText];
    }
}

- (void)dismissSearch
{
    [self.searchBar performSelector: @selector(resignFirstResponder)
                  withObject: nil
                  afterDelay: 0.1];

    self.searchResultsTable.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using the `UISearchController` in **iOS 8** and up, you'll want to simply subclass the `UISearchController`. For completeness, you may also want to hide the *cancel* button, as I did, since clearing the text from the `UISearchBar` is effectively a cancel on the search. I've added that code below if you want to use it.

The benefit of this is that you'll be able to use this for any class and any view, rather than requiring a subclass of `UIViewController`. I'll even include how I initialize my `UISearchController` at the bottom of this solution.

### FJSearchBar

This class only needs to be overridden if you want to hide the cancel button as I did. Marking `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO` doesn't seem to work in **iOS 8**. I haven't tested **iOS 9**.

#### FJSearchBar.h

Empty, but placed here for completeness.

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchBar : UISearchBar

@end
```

#### FJSearchBar.m

```
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchBar

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton {
    // do nothing
}

- (void)setShowsCancelButton:(BOOL)showsCancelButton animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // do nothing
}

@end
```

### FJSearchController

Here's where you want to make the real changes. I split the `UISearchBarDelegate` into its own category because, IMHO, the categories make the classes cleaner and easier to maintain. If you want to keep the delegate within the main class interface/implementation, you're more than welcome to do so.

#### FJSearchController.h

```
@import UIKit;

@interface FJSearchController : UISearchController

@end

@interface FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate) <UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

#### FJSearchController.m

```
#import "FJSearchController.h"
#import "FJSearchBar.h"

@implementation FJSearchController {
@private
    FJSearchBar *_searchBar;
    BOOL _clearedOutside;
}

- (UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        // if you're not hiding the cancel button, simply uncomment the line below and delete the FJSearchBar alloc/init
        // _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar = [[FJSearchBar alloc] init];
        _searchBar.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

@end

@implementation FJSearchController (UISearchBarDelegate)

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // if we cleared from outside then we should not allow any new editing
    BOOL shouldAllowEditing = !_clearedOutside;
    _clearedOutside = NO;
    return shouldAllowEditing;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    // hide the keyboard since the user will no longer add any more input
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // the user cleared the search while not in typing mode, so we should deactivate searching
        self.active = NO;
        _clearedOutside = YES;
        return;
    }
    // update the search results
    [self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];
}

@end
```

Some parts to note:

1. I've put the search bar and the `BOOL` as private variables instead of properties because

   - They're more lightweight than private properties.
   - They don't need to be seen or modified by the outside world.
2. We check whether the `searchBar` is the first responder. If it's not, then we actually deactivate the search controller because the text is empty and we're no longer searching. If you **really** want to be sure, you can also ensure that `searchText.length == 0`.
3. `searchBar:textDidChange:` is invoked before `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`, which is why we handled it in this order.
4. I update the search results every time the text changes, but you may want to move the `[self.searchResultsUpdater updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self];` to `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` if you only want the search performed after the user presses the *Search* button.

Answer (score -1):

I've run into this several times now.  I really appreciate the answers that people have given.

Ultimately, I would really like to see Apple just allow us (the developers) to detect when the clear button has been pressed.

It is obvious that pressing it gets detected because any text in the search box gets cleared.

I am guessing that it just isn't very high up on their list of priorities right now... But I really wish someone at Apple would give UISearchBar a little love!