# iPhone perform action when UITextField / UISearchBar's clear button is pressed

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uisearchbar

Is it possible to gain access to a delegate method that will allow additional actions to be performed when the "clear" button is pressed on a UITextField / UISearchBar?

Thanks

Comment: check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092246/uisearchbar-clearbutton-forces-the-keyboard-to-appear

Answer (score 35):

See: [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldClear:)

If you set your view controller as the delegate for your text field (can be done in interface builder), you can use:

```
- (void)clearSearchTextField
{
  ...
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
  if (textField == self.searchTextField) [self clearSearchTextField];
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**For Swift 3:**

To perform an action when the "clear" button is pressed on a UITextField

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == yourTextFieldName {
        // do some action
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `UISearchBar` you will want to implement `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`.

This is triggered before `func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)` and before `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool` as well.

You implementation should look something like this:

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText == "" {
            //Code to execute when search is cleared
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is called, even if I clear text by backspace. But how to detect total clear text?

Answer (score 0):

When you clear the text field several events will happen that you will have access to through either the [UISearchDisplayDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchDisplayDelegate) or the UISearchBarDelegate such as `searchBar:textDidChange` and `searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString`

This will also cause the search table to hide so it will trigger

```
searchDisplayController:willHideSearchResultsTableView  
searchDisplayController:didHideSearchResultsTableView
```

When the search table will hide you can check if the search text is empty and then do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score -1):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852509/91458 – it’s for a searchBar but should apply to a textField as well.