# Search controller with navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I have navigation controller which has **.hidesBarOnSwipe = true**.
As well when I perform search my navigation controller goes up and hides (as it should by default).

But if I try search something and then press (x) to clean what I've already written my navigation bar overlaps search bar but the second is still active and I can write something and it performs search.

So the question is how I can find method that invoked when I tap (x) button on search bar.

And how can I make my navigation bar be fixed and hidden while my search bar is still active because if it is still active I can swipe down I got my navigation bar overlapping search bar again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get this function of **X** pressed

```
 func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText == "" {
        print("SearchBar text cleared!")
        // do something whatever you need
    }
}
```

or use

```
func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

 // do something here
return true
}
```

**Swift3**

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
// do something here
return true
}
```

or use this

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
if (searchBar.text == "") {
    //Clear stuff here
}
}
```

for more information you can get the samples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190459/dismissing-keyboard-from-uisearchbar-when-the-x-button-is-tapped)

Comment: Thank you. But when I just tapped on search field it still can be covered by navigation controller. Your method shows that I can change property of navigation controller only after search filed gets "" not from the beginning.

Comment: on beginning textFieldShouldClear method is called

Comment: Thank you! I missed that method you mentioned last. That did the trick in the pair of ...DidEndEditing!

Comment: @wm.p1us - nothing problem, small mistake thats all

Comment: Thank you. It is also helped me