# How to add a method to an existing protocol in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, protocols

I want to extend or add another method to an existing protocol. Although the protocol in particular is not important, this is what I am trying to do.

```
@protocol NSMatrixDelegate
- (void)myNewMethod:(id)sender;
@end
```

The compiler warns that I have a duplicate declaration of the same protocol. How would I do this properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't define categories for protocols.  There are 2 ways around this:

- use a new formal protocol
- use an informal protocol and runtime checking

## Formal Protocol

Defining a new formal protocol would look like this:

```
@protocol MyCustomMatrixDelegate <NSMatrixDelegate>

- (void) myNewMethod:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then you would make your custom class conform to `<MyCustomMatrixDelegate>` instead of `<NSMatrixDelegate>`.  If you use this approach, there's something to be aware of:  `[self delegate]` will likely be declared as `id<NSMatrixDelegate>`.  This means that you can't do `[[self delegate] myNewMethod:obj]`, because `<NSMatrixDelegate>` does not declare the `myNewMethod:` method.

The way around this is to retype the `delegate` object via casting.  Maybe something like:

```
- (id<MyCustomMatrixDelegate>) customDelegate {
  return (id<MyCustomMatrixDelegate>)[self delegate];
}
```

(However, you might want to do some type checking first, like:

```
if ([[self delegate] conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyCustomMatrixDelegate)]) {
  return (id<MyCustomMatrixDelegate>)[self delegate];
}
return nil;
```

)

And then you'd do:

```
[[self customDelegate] myNewMethod:obj];
```

## Informal Protocol

This is really a fancy name for a category on `NSObject`:

```
@interface NSObject (MyCustomMatrixDelegate)

- (void) myNewMethod:(id)sender;

@end
```

Then you just don't implement the method.  In your class that would send the method, you'd do:

```
if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(myNewMethod:)]) {
  [[self delegate] myNewMethod:someSenderValue];
}
```

Comment: I tried the Formal Protocol method. It works, however the compiler warns that the custom method cannot be found in the protocol. I added the formal protocol to the interface of the delegate and included the delegate's header in the implementation file of the objet that I am sending the delegate message to. Do you have any idea why it is still complaining? Thanks