# How to dismiss the Keyboard using UIsearchBar Delegate methods? i tried every method but no use.

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i am using a UIsearchBar in my app, i tried all methods in UISearchBar Delegate to dismiss the keyboard but no use. could anyone help me out.

some codes i tried

1.

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

2.

```
-(BOOL) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

3.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
{
     [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Did u set the delegate to self?

Comment: USe a break point and check delegate methods are being called ?

Comment: is that delegate method calling o r not did u add <UISearchBarDelegate> or not

Comment: are you getting the answer?

Comment: - (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)bar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"searchBar:textDidChange: isFirstResponder: %i", [self.searchBar isFirstResponder]);
    if(![searchBar isFirstResponder]) {
        // user tapped the 'clear' button
        shouldBeginEditing = NO;
        // do whatever I want to happen when the user clears the search...
    }
} ue this

Comment: refer this linkk also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092246/uisearchbar-clearbutton-forces-the-keyboard-to-appear

Comment: ya i tried but my prob doesn't solve..

Comment: To Rushi:  i set the delegate method to self.

Comment: my delegate methods are not called, but i have included <UISearchBarDelegate>

Answer (score 30):

First of all you should implement [`UISearchBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)  in your class  &  check if you have connected the to your `UISearchBar` or not?

If you are adding `UISearchBar` through IB then you should select delegate property of the UISearchBar to the file's owner. You should make sure that you are connecting  `IBOutlet` for the `UISearchBar` in the code properly .

If you are adding `UISearchBar` via code then you should set the delegate yourself in the code like this `searchBar.delegate=self;`

Next step is to make sure that delegate methods are being called, which is obvious if you have connected delegate properly, best thing to check stuff is putting break pointer in your code or print through `NSLog`.

Finally use this method to hide the keyboard if you want to hide when user clicks to search

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

OR you could try when editing finished

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: -(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar1 resignFirstResponder];
  
}

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

Set the delegate on the search bar and check whether the IBOutlet is connected or not

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: i tried the above code also, but task accomplished

Comment: Thank You guys, I solved my problem using UIsearchDisplayDelegate instead UISearchDelegate. Need Your Continued support.